# Expanding just last row of groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I need get mean of expanding grouped by name.

I already have this code:

```py
data = {
  'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
  'number': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['mean_number'] = df.groupby('name')['number'].apply(
  lambda s: s.expanding().mean().shift()
)
```

Ps: I use .shift() for the mean not to include the current line

Result in this:

```py
   id name  number  mean_number
0   1    A       1          NaN
1   2    B       3          NaN
2   3    A       5          1.0
3   4    B       7          3.0
4   5    A       9          3.0
5   6    B      11          5.0
6   7    A      13          5.0
7   8    B      15          7.0
```

Works, but I only need the last result of each groupby.

```py
   id name  number  mean_number
6   7    A      13          5.0
7   8    B      15          7.0
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the mean of only these last lines, because in a very large dataset, it takes a long time to create the variables of all the lines and filter only the last ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the last two mean numbers you can just take the sum and count per group and calculate the values like this:

```
groups = df.groupby('name').agg(name=("name", "first"), s=("number", "sum"), c=("number", "count")).set_index("name")

groups
       s  c
name       
A     28  4
B     36  4
```

Then you can use `.tail()` to get the last row for each group

```
tail = df.groupby('name').tail(1).set_index("name")

tail
      id  number
name            
A      7      13
B      8      15
```

Calculate the mean like this

```
(groups.s - tail.number) / (groups.c - 1)

name
A    5.0
B    7.0
```